# Java parseInt from String, not able use array

Tags: java, string, parseint

I'm writing a programm which finds the largest number in a .txt file and outputs it. I'm trying to solve it myself but end up back at the same problem "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"... For less confusion I'm using class files (Input/Output) from my school.

```
public class Zahlenstatistik {

        public static void main (String[] args) {

                    In.open("test.txt"); 
    String numbers = In.readFile();
    Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int i = 0;
    String[] alle_zahlen = numbers.split("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < alle_zahlen.length; i++)
        if (max < Integer.parseInt(alle_zahlen[i]))
            max = Integer.parseInt(alle_zahlen[i]);

    System.out.println("Die groeste Zahl ist: " + max);

        }

     }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Zahlenstatistik.main(Zahlenstatistik.java:12)
```

test.txt file:

`33
123
0
55
800
-55
-1
777`

Comment: numbers[i] is wrong it is an string, you should use array[i] instead

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at Zahlenstatistik.main(Zahlenstatistik.java:12)` when i replace it with array[i]

Comment: make it array.length - 1 instead of array.length, Because array.length property starts from 1 and your iteration starts from 0

Comment: @user7790438 if you mean in loop limit, then no, `i < array.length` is correct;  using `i < array.length-1` would miss the last element.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the `for` statement is wrong.  It means the loop does nothing.  The following `if` **is not part of the loop** and **it should be**. Removing the semicolon will make it so.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, I think there is also a bad semi-colon on the `if` statement. And thank you for making the note on the `array.length`.

Comment: @KevinO @Kevin Anderson brings me back to the old error:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33
"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Zahlenstatistik.main(Zahlenstatistik.java:13) `

Comment: @Ridi, I have added an answer that should address the number format exception. Assuming it is not a file encoding issue, the most likely explanation is extraneous characters on the input. The answer below shows how to strip or replace these characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in Java 8:

```
    package com.sial.workarounds;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    public class Zahlenstatistik {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String numbers = String.join("\n", reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        reader.close();
        Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int i = 0;
        String[] alle_zahlen = numbers.split("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < alle_zahlen.length; i++)
            if (max < Integer.parseInt(alle_zahlen[i]))
                max = Integer.parseInt(alle_zahlen[i]);

        System.out.println("Die groeste Zahl ist: " + max);

    }
}
```

Comment: this worked, now I need to know where the problem was :) thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

You have used `numbers` instead of `array`, where numbers is a String. Also, I would suggest using a better name than `array` for naming an array

Comment: One should choose names for one's variables as carefully as if one were naming a first born child (Coplien, foreword to Clean Code)

Comment: @KevinO I like that analogy.  Mind if I borrow it?

Comment: @KevinAnderson, the concept is in the foreword to the book *Clean Code*, but I think the actual words are just slightly different. So, go for it!

Answer (score 1):

The question has mutated a bit, but here is a potential suggestion to resolve the invalid number format. Please note that file encoding may also play a role. It is also possible to strip other characters from the input via something like

```
String rawValue = alle_zahlen[i].replaceAll("[^-?\\d]+", "");
```

Also, good practice is to always use braces, so I've added them

```
for(i = 0; i < alle_zahlen.length; i++) {
  String rawValue = alle_zahlen[i].trim();
  try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(rawValue);
    max = Math.max(max, value);
    // NOTE: instead of Math.max, can also do (which is essentially what
    //        Math.max() does)
    // max = max > value ? max : value;
  } //try
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} //for
System.out.println("Die groeste Zahl ist: " + max);
```

If you'd like to use Java 8 Streams, you could also do:

```
System.out.println("Die groeste Zahl ist: " +
      Arrays.stream(alle_zahlen)
        .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^-?\\d]+", "")))
        .max()
        .getAsInt());
```

Both approaches tested against a mock input of:

```
final String numbers = "33 \n123\n0\n55\n800\n-55\n-1\n777\n";
final String[] alle_zahlen = numbers.split("\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler returns the error: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String`, it is telling you that you are doing an action that expects an array but is getting a string. In this case, you are using a string in place of an array.

For instance, you are using `numbers` as an array when you write: `max = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);` and `if (max < Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]));`.

Instead, you should be using `array`.

Thus, you should change your code to 
`max = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);` and `if (max < Integer.parseInt(array[i]));`

Additionally, you should not have `;` after your for loops or if statements. This changes how the statement is used, and it will just sit there and increment your variable without actually repeating anything. This ultimately caused your out of bounds exception.

Comment: thank you for your help :) ! but one thing is missing thank you @user7790438  "array.length -1" did the trick, holy shit finally :D. thank you very much everybody!

Comment: Thanks! I updated it. I didn't check myself to ensure that the fix was proper.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Stream of Integer

```
s.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get());
```

you can add .parallel if you want to.

Comment: Except that the original was O(n).  This is less efficient.